# Teradata - How can I extract all rows of a partition using the qualify statement?

Tags: teradata

I have some data in a table that looks like the following

```
Username     Loaddate
--------    ----------
GITTES1     2016-01-25
GITTES1     2016-01-25
GITTES1     2016-01-25
GITTES1     2016-01-24
GITTES1     2016-01-23
```

Is there a way I can extract all the rows for GITTES1 with LOADDATE = 2016-01-25 using qualify statement. The number of rows in this partition can vary from 0 to n .. and there are multiple such users.

Comment: What's wrong with `where  LOADDATE = '2016-01-25'`?

Comment: the dates are different for different users .. and there are hundreds of users ..

Comment: Can you elaborate on *dates are different for different users*? Where are those dates coming from? And why `QUALIFY`?

Comment: sorry dnoeth for the late reply ... the dates are entered are system dates which signify when the record was inserted .. i was thinking of qualify because there might be other users in the table with same scenario and but instead of 2016-01-25 there may be a different date .. the bottom line is I will have to partition by username,loaddate and pull only the records of the earliest date .. can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the records with the earliest `Loaddate` per `Username`, try

```
select Username, Loaddate from table
   qualify rank() over (partition by Username order by Loaddate asc) = 1;
```

If you want the records with the *latest* `Loaddate` instead, replace `asc` with `desc` in the above.